# Why python ignores the if sentence which has dict.keys()?

Tags: python, dictionary

I made an if sentence to determine whether inputted name is in the voted dictionary or not, but it doesn't work.

I printed `voter in voted.keys()` to see that it is True or False. But as I thought, it was False!

```py
voted = {'John':True, 'Alice':False, 'Rosa':True}

print(voted, end = '\n\n')

while 1:
    voter = input('Enter your name : ')

    if voter == '':
        break

    if voter in voted.keys() == False:
        print(voter,'has no voting rights.', end= '\n\n')
        continue


    if voted[voter] == True:
        print(voter, 'already voted!', end= '\n\n')
    elif voted[voter] == False:
        print(voter, ', please vote!', end= '\n\n')
        voted[voter] = True

print(voted)
```

I expected to print 'NAME has no voting rights.' but the actual output is the error code 'if voted[voter] == True: KeyError: 'NAME''

Comment: A part enclosed in ''' is just a string and won't be executed as code.

Comment: Trust your syntax highlighter.

Comment: Ah I just used it to emphasize the code! But I think I should remove that

Comment: What name are you entering?

Comment: It works [as expected for me](https://ideone.com/fuy3Jb)

Comment: I enter the name that are not included in voted dictionary! I'm making the code that if I enter the name that are not included in voted dictionary, print the 'NAME has no voting rights.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You comment out the section that check if the voter is already vote, and its a dict so you need to initalize the value of `voter` in `voted`

```py
while 1:
    voter = input('Enter your name : ')

    if voter == '':
        break

    if voter not in voted.keys():
        print(voter,'has no voting rights.', end= '\n\n')
        continue

    if voted[voter] == True:
        print(voter, 'already voted!', end= '\n\n')
    elif voted[voter] == False:
        print(voter, ', please vote!', end= '\n\n')
        voted[voter] = True

print(voted)
```

Comment: @YSuho mark as current answer if you think it asnwer you question, and also read chepner answer its has some more details :)

Answer (score 1):

Both `in` and `==` are considered comparison operators, and so are subject to chaining (which lets you write things like `1 < x < 5` instead of `1 < x and x < 5`). That expression is equivalent to

```
voter in voted.keys() and voter.keys() == False
```

Since the `keys` method never returns a Boolean value, that comparison is always false. Here is a simpler example, along with a use of parentheses to resolve the problem:

```
>>> 3 in [1,2,3] == True
False
>>> (3 in [1,2,3]) == True
True
```

Since `in` already evaluates to a Boolean value, you don't need an additional comparison. Use `not in` instead.

```
if voter not in voted:
```

You also don't need to call `keys`; `in` and `not in` automatically check against the keys of a `dict`.